# How to store Menu in MySQL Database?

Tags: database-design

I am working on a Website for a Restaurant and I need to store all the content of their menu on a MySQL Databse.

Now, what I cannot understand is how I can organize it. In other words, the restaurant has non-alcholic drinks and alcholic drinks, it has different sales/offers, it has different types of foods(diary or salad or beef) and so on.

The website would be organized in "Cards" which is a simple image that once clicked will show up a menu for that specific item, for example, if there is an image of a salad, if the client clicks on the image, a menu/list with all types of salads will show up.

I don't have any problems building it, the only problem is how I can organize the Database. Does it has to be in multiple tables? Does it need any links? Since every item is going to have a price, a description and a title I need to do it right the first time since there are lots of items.

Also, the client would need be able to add each items to the "cart" because this specific restaurant wants to deliver to home. How would I go about that? Do I need to create a separate table for the cart items?

What I am looking for is a simple yet effective way to manage all the orders and each individual item. If I have not beed very clear I can easily add more details if needed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please try creating the mysql table, then show us what you have done.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand what help you expect from us! It seems that you are not familiar with database design principles at all. This is not a problem, we have all been down this path once. However, what you need is to read books / tutorials on database design first because this is a very broad ranging topic and we cannot describe all ins and outs of database design for you in a single SO answer. Once you learn the foundations from a book, you start designing your schema and if you have a **specific** problem, like implementing a many to many relationship, then you can ask us here.

Comment: BTW, you can always use a ready-made solution like wordpress - It will save you the hassle of building everything yourself from scratch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create 2 masters here,

1. One for category of the food like alcoholic drink, none alcoholic drink, salads, dairy etc
2. Another for discount percent or offers offered. Depending upon the format of discount, you can further break it down to multiple master tables say one for percentage of discount offered(say 30% off), offers like 'Buy 1 get 1 free' etc. Totally depends on the use case

Now after creating masters you can create your Menu table. It will consist of Id, name, description (Any other meta data associated with the food), category type(Foreign key, reference point 1), discount (foreign key, reference point 2)

Coming to your use cases

1. Showing users cards - card tittles can be extracted from the master of categories
2. Showing relevant menu when clicked on card - can be extracted by query database based on the card id user clicked on
3. Adding items to cart - this can further be broken down
   i. you can create a Users table with id, name, etc .
   ii. another table with cart details with columns such as id, status(delivered, canceled, etc), menu id(foreign key), user id(foreign key) quantity, notes etc